# Make an alert only appear when app is opened

Tags: java, android, alert, onstart

Is there a way to make an alert only appear when the app is opened? I'm creating an alert in onStart() in my MainActivity and whenever I go back to that activity in the app, it shows the alert again which can be annoying to the user. Or is there a way to create a "got it" button and then turn off the alert? Here is my code:

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Instructions")
            .setMessage("Hello! To begin, select a map from the list to train with. Make sure" +
                    " you are on the correct floor.")
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            })
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .show();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when another activity comes to foreground upon your          `MainActivity`  makes your activity goes to `OnPause()`.
Then when you go back to your MainActivity. The system calls 
`onStart()` again. [See The activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png)

-First Solution

```
public class TestActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        showAlertDialog();
    }
}

private void showAlertDialog() {
    // code to show alert dialog.
}
```

}

-Second Solution

```
public class TestActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static boolean isAlertDialogShownBefore = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (!isAlertDialogShownBefore) {
        showAlertDialog();
        isAlertDialogShownBefore = true;
    }
}

private void showAlertDialog() {
    // code to show alert dialog.
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    isAlertDialogShownBefore = false;
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

Comment: When I do this the alert does not show up each time the app is opened but only the first time after installing the app.

Comment: If u have used the first solution u have to put the isShown variable  with false in onDestroy() of MainActivity.

Or u can use the second solution if(savedInstanceState == null){
   showAlertDialog();
 }

Comment: thank you but it is still not doing what I want it to do. When I reopen the app from the paused state it does not show

Comment: May you clarify what you want ? , U want the alert appear every time the application is opened in MainActivity   and  not to be shown when you go back to MainActivity?

Answer (score 0):

Put that code in onCreate method of your activity. Check for saveInstanceState for null, if it is then show your alertDialog